# Doubt about construction of Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For defining linear transformation from one set to another is it necessary that both sets should be vector spaces?I think domain set should be vector space because input can be any linear combination of vectors.Am I right?What about range set.Is it necessary for range set to be vector space too?I am trying to construct such linear transformation in which range set is not vector space but not getting it.

Comment: Isn't that just part of the definition of a linear map?

Comment: By definition, linear transformations are functions from one vector space to another vector space, over the same field, that are additive and homogeneous. You can certainly try to talk about functions with domain a vector space and codomain some other structure, and ask that they have certain properties, but then you shouldn't call them "linear transformations", just like you shouldn't talk about a function being "continuous" unless both your domain and range are topological spaces.

Comment: Linearity of the map induces a vector space structure on the range, regardless of whether or not it started out as a vector space.

Comment: @amd: What? Say I have $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $C_{10}$ (cyclic group of order $10$, and I define a map $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to C_{10}$ by $(x,y)\mapsto \lfloor x\rfloor\bmod 10$ (viewing $C_{10}$ as the additive group of integers modulo $10$). How do I induce a vector space structure on the range by declaring the map to be linear?  Certainly if I have a bijection I can use transport of structure, but otherwise, I have no idea what you could possibly mean.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I didn’t mean that one can simply pull a map out of a hat and declare it to be linear. That declaration is nonsensical unless you also define what $af(x)+bf(y)$ means, and do so in a way that is consistent with the definition of linearity of $f$. If the domain is a vector space, you can’t help but end up with a vector space for the range as well. I suspect that we’re basically in violent agreement here.

Comment: @amd: In other words: you can’t call it a linear transformation unless you have (or are able to define) some structure on the range that makes it into a vector space?  That’s very different from saying that the map “induces” a structure... to say that a map “induces a structure” means that you start with the map and you end up with the structure (like you do with transport of structure in a bijection; or like you can use a map to define a topology as the finest topology that makes the map continuous, etc).